# Wildcard in sed command to replace string not working

Tags: string, bash, macos, sed, replace

I'm trying to use the `sed` command in terminal to replace a specific line in all my text files with a certain extension by a specific string:

```
sed -i.bak '35s/^.*$/5\) 1\-4/' fitting_file*.feedme
```

So I am trying to replace line 35 in each of these files with the string "5) 1-4". When I run an `ls fitting_file*.feedme | wc -l` command in this directory, I get 221 files. However, when I run the above `sed` command, it only edits the FIRST file in the order of `ls fitting_file*.feedme`. I know this because `grep '5) 1-4' fitting_file*.feedme` continually only returns the first file on the list after I run the replacement command. I also tried replacing `fitting_file*.feedme` with a space-separated list of a couple of these files in my `sed` command as a test, but it still only operated on the one I chose to list first. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` operates on a *single* stream. It essentially concats all the files together and treats that as a single stream. So it replaces the 35th line of the big concatenated stream.

To see this, make a 20 line file called A and a 20 line file called B. Apply your sed command as

```
sed -i.bak '35s/^.*$/5\) 1\-4/' A B
```

and you will see the 15th line of B replaced.

I think this should answer your direct question. As far how to get done what you like, I assume you've already figured out that wrapping your sed command in a `for` is one way to do it. :)

Comment: There's no reason to escape `)` and `-` in - they're just literal characters. Don't wrap your sed command in a for loop, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219.

Comment: In GNU sed the `-i` option treats each file separately and I do not see this `single stream` effect. Also note to concatenate a number of files but treat each file separately us the `-s` option. Finally, instead of `s/.*/replacement/` use the `c` command to  replace a line(s).

Comment: @EdMorton - thanks but I didn't want to change the OP string, but probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: @potong Interesting. I have a Mac, so it's BSD sed, where you do get the single stream effect. Always good to point out the differences between GNU and BSD. They differ so much in even basic commands like ps, grep, and sed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Create a file containing your sed instruction like this

```
#!/bin/bash 
sed -i.bak '35s/^.*$/5\) 1\-4/' $1
exit 0
```

and call it prog.sh. Next make it executable :

```
chmod u+x prog.sh
```

now you can solve your problem using

```
find . -name fitting_file\*.feedme -exec ./prog.sh {} \;
```

You could do all this on one line but frankly the number of escapes required is a bit much. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're trying to do without using a [shell loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219) is:

```
awk -i inplace -v inplace::suffix=.bak 'FNR==35{$0="5) 1-4"}1' fitting_file*.feedme
```

Note that unlike sed which can just count lines across all input files, awk has `NR` to track the number of records (lines by default) across all files and `FNR` for the same but just within the current file.

The above uses GNU awk for inplace editing just like GNU sed has `-i` for that. The default awk on MacOS is BSD awk, not GNU awk, but you should install GNU awk as it doesn't have all the bugs/quirks that BSD awk does and it has a ton of extremely useful extensions.

If you just want to use MacOS's awk then it'd be something like:

```
find . -name 'fitting_file*.feedme' -exec sh -c "\
    awk 'FNR==35{\$0=\"5) 1-4\"}1' \"\$1\" > \"\$1.bak\" &&
    mv -- \"\$1.bak\" \"\$1\"
" sh {} \;
```

which is obviously getting kinda complicated - I'd probably put the awk+mv script in a file to execute from `sh -c` or just resort to a shell loop myself if faced with that alternative (or a similar quoting nightmare with xargs)!